# Cassandra QUORUM write consistency level and multiple DC

Tags: cassandra

I'm a bit confused about how QUORUM write selects nodes to write into in case of multiple DC.
Suppose, for example, that I have a 3 DC cluster with 3 nodes in each DC, and the replications factor is 2, so that the number of replicas needed to achieve QUORUM is 3. Note: this is just an example to help me formulate my question and not the actual configuration.
My question is the following: in case of write, how these 3 replicas will be distributed across all the DCs in my cluster? Is it possible that all 3 replicas will end up in the same DC?

Comment: Yes it is possible that data is read/written from the same DC. In case if you were thinking you should use QUORUM or not in case of multiple DCs. But, in the background a node repair process will begin which will update the nodes with newest value for each data center.

Answer (score 2):

The replication is defined at the key space level. So for example

```
create keyspace test with replication = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 2, 'DC2' : 2, 'DC3' : 2 };
```

As you can see clearly each DC will hold two copies of data for that keyspace and not more. You could have another key space in the same cluster defined only to replicate in one DC and not the other two. So its flexible.

Now for consistency, with 3 DCs and RF=2 in each DC, you have 6 copies of data. By definition of Quorum a majority (which is RF/2 + 1) of those 6 members needs to acknowledge the write, before claiming that the write was successful. So **4 nodes needs to respond** for a quorum write here and these 4 members could be a combination of nodes from any DC. Remember the number of replicas matter to calculate quorum and not the total no. of nodes in DC.

On a side note, in Cassandra, RF=2 is as good as RF=1. To simplify, lets imagine a 3 node single DC situation. With RF=2 there are two copies of data and in order to achieve quorum ((RF=2)/2 + 1), 2 nodes needs to acknowledge the write.  So both the nodes always have to be available. Even if one node fails the writes will start to fail. Event another node can take hints here, but your reads with quorum are bound to fail. **So fault tolerance of node failure is equal to zero in this situation.**

> You could use local_quorum to speed up the writes instead of quorum. Its sacrifice of consistency over speed. Welcome to **"eventually consistency"**.

Comment: Agree.  The OP should definitely be using LOCAL_QUORUM here.

Answer (score 1):

**Consistency Level Determine the number of replicas on which the write must succeed before returning an acknowledgment to the client application**

> Even at low consistency levels, the write is still sent to all replicas for the written key, even replicas in other data centers. The consistency level just determines how many replicas are required to respond that they received the write.

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

So If you set Consistency Level to `QUORUM`. I assume each DC have RF of 2. And so QUORUM is 3. **So all your write still send all replicas of each DC (3 * 2 = 6 node) And will wait for 3 node to success after that it will send the acknowledgment to the client**